# Do subtype changes remain after a card is transformed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

Say I have an [Olivia, Mobilized for War](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOlivia%2c%20Mobilized%20for%20War%5d) on the field, who has this ability:

> Whenever another creature enters the battlefield under your control,
>   you may discard a card. If you do, put a +1/+1 counter on that
>   creature, it gains haste until end of turn, and it becomes a Vampire
>   in addition to its other types.

I play a Werewolf and discard a card to pay for Olivia's ability. The Werewolf is also a Vampire now.

A turn passes without anybody playing spells, so the Werewolf transforms. Is it still a Vampire? Or is it only the subtypes written on the card's new face?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_21031101.pdf):

> 711.7. When a double-faced permanent transforms, it doesn't become a new object. Any effects that applied to that permanent will continue to apply to it after it transforms.

So your Werewolf will keep its Vampire subtype.